# websocket Clank bundle can't connect

Tags: websocket

I'm using clank bundle and I want to test if socket server is running without problem 
I have set the configuration as follow :

```
# Clank Configuration
clank:
    web_socket_server:
        port: 8080        #The port the socket server will listen on
        host: domain.com #(optional) The host ip to bind to
```

the port 8080 is open and tested 
after adding the two js files : `autobahn.min.js` and `clank.js` I do the following :

```
var myClank = Clank.connect("wss://domain.com:8080"); // I use SSL

        myClank.on("socket/connect", function(session){
            //session is an Autobahn JS WAMP session.

            console.log("Successfully Connected!");
        })

        myClank.on("socket/disconnect", function(error){
            //error provides us with some insight into the disconnection: error.reason and error.code

            console.log("Disconnected for " + error.reason + " with code " + error.code);
        })
```

note that the server is already running with the command :

```
php app/console clank:server
```

the problem is I can't get the success message in my console.. When I stop clank server , it outputs the failure message.
I don't know what's happening please help me ..

Comment: What is `clank.js`? In general, you need to provide more context ..

Comment: https://github.com/JDare/ClankBundle

Comment: The only thing I can say (since I don't know that stuff layered on top of Autobahn): you need to use AutobahnJS at most 0.8.2 (WAMPv1) - since Ratchet does only provide WAMPv1, not WAMPv2.

Comment: https://github.com/cboden/Ratchet/issues/168#issuecomment-43770529

Comment: Try: `ab.version()` to get version of legacy AutobahnJS library.

Comment: I replaced the autobahn , and ab.version says :0.8.2

Comment: There is this service as well : 
http://www.websocket.org/echo.html
I tested on my socket server but no answers .. 
I'm using nginx , if this can add anything

Comment: This seems to be very troublesome , I only want to integrate websockets with symfony2 can you advise me any bundle  or direct way ?

Comment: no, sorry. I don't use PHP, Symfony2 and all that. FWIW, you don't need AutobahnJS for WebSocket at all.

Comment: I managed making it work on ws , but I couldn't do it on wss any ideas ?

Comment: use a valid certificate (not self-signed, domain matching, etc, etc). run on port 443.

Comment: I have it signed by a third party. 
I'll test on 443 and be back to you

Comment: but 443 is already used by ssl itself .. ?

Comment: yes. 443 is default port for TLS (and WSS), and that means you can (should) use `wss://example.com` (no port) to connect in JS. also: signed by third party isn't enough .. the certificate issuer (the CA) must be installed in browser's default trusted CAs list to make it work without issues. e.g. StartSSL, Verisign, etc

Comment: I have the https green so the certificate is valid , no port hah ? 
Ok let me try that

Comment: I don't know on which port should I launch my websocket server .. 
I let it 8080 but I got this error message 
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 
In JS , I didn't precise a port

Comment: sorry: this isn't the place for chatting .. hence last my comment: launch server on port 443, but don't give port in JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54151/discussion-between-sekai-and-oberstet).